# Given radius, and many vertices on it, how can I find center of a sphere?

Tags: geometry

I have a sphere, I know its radius. I also have the coordinates of 500 vertices which are on the sphere. How can I find the center coordinates of a sphere? Is there an easy way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this just solving simultaneous equations?

Comment: Assuming the sphere is in $\mathbb{R}^3$ its equation is $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 = r^2$ where $(a,b,c)$ is the center and $r$ is the radius. Just plug in some of the coordinates of your points and get some equations to solve for $a,b,c$.

Comment: Or look at Simon Watfa's answer here (http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/geometry/sphere4pts.html) for a nice way of doing it given $4$ non-coplanar points on the sphere (it turns this is enough to get a unique sphere).

Comment: If you know four points, but you don't know the radius, then you can find the center of the sphere. In this problem, you have a bit more information than you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just four vertices $A,B,C,D$. Let $O_A$ be the circumcenter of $BCD$ and $l_A$ the line through $O_A$ that is orthogonal to the $BCD$-plane. Let $O_D$ be the circumcenter of $ABC$ and $l_D$ the line through $O_A$ that is orthogonal to the $ABC$-plane. Then $l_A$ and $l_D$ meet in the centre of the sphere.